# Please help identify these 2.0mm pitch wafer wire to board connectors

Tags: identification, connector, uart

Please help me find these 2.0mm pitched 6 pin connectors. They are used in this application for UART communication between a wifi module and the main board.

The closest thing I found was [YYECOM YWPHB200 Series](https://www.yyecon.com/ywphb200-series-wire-to-board-connector-pitch2-00mm-079-single-row-side-entry-smd-type-wire-rangeawg-24-30.html), but they don't seem to have the vertical style (top loading) connector or the matching plug.

I want to match these connectors for my project to replace the 2.4 GHz wifi module with one that supports 5 GHz WiFi and I'm not able to find who makes/sells them:

[image: latching plug]

[image: smd socket]

[image: smd socket view 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those that find this question later:

These are called "HY2.0 2.0mm Connectors".  The 4pin version seems to also be used by Arduino [Grove sensors](https://www.seeedstudio.com/category/Grove-c-1003.html).  The HY2.0 connectors are made by many companies in China (LHE, Taihua, etc.) and can be [purchased from aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2255800658080449.html?gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt).  I also found someone on ebay selling the housing already wired once I knew the correct search terms.

[image: adapter type s]

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for providing clear and complete information. It allowed me to use my [Connector Identification Utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_1row_latch_w2b_conn&f=discrete_1row_latch_w2b_conn_2) that lists these possibilities:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- JST - PA
- JST - PA + PAF
- Molex - Micro-Lock 503660 + 503658
- Molex - Sherlock

Comment: Thank you for this nice work on the ID tool, but I did not find what I was looking for this time on your site.